# Is there a simplification for x power log to base (1/x)?

Tags: math, logarithm, exponent

Is there a simplification for x^(log base (1/x) of N)?

Comment: Wouldn't http://math.stackexchange.com be a better place for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's `1 / N` (the reciprocal of `N`), provided of course that both `N` and `x` are positive and `x != 1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
x^(log[1/x](n)) = e^(log[1/x](n)*ln(x)) = e^((ln(n)/ln(1/x))*ln(x)) = e^(ln(n)*ln(x)/(-ln(x)) = e^(-ln(n)) = 1/n
```